# Recover from problem in Linq submit

Tags: linq-to-sql

If I change the values of a Linq class and then try to submit the changes to the database and get a conflict like string is to long or value can not be null, the database will not be changes. But the question is what's the best way is to recover from this commit problem and role back the values in the class to the unchanged values.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to SQL creates a transaction for each query you execute, which will rollback on failure.  If you'd like more control over the transaction, like say if you want to perform many operations on your own, you can create a [`TransactionScope`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2007/08/06/linq-to-sql-using-transaction.aspx) around your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would think more in terms of how do you prevent the error from occuring in the first place.  If you know there is a possibility that a submit will fail due to a string length, or null value, you should be checking for this prior to committing the records.

Remember, an exception is exactly that -- an exception to something you didn't think about when you were developing the solution.

Comment: A transaction can be useful to avoid concurrency issues as well.  And in the end, you really just never know when a simple query will return an error due to something machine related, even though it would have otherwise worked just fine.  In those cases, having a rollback mechanism is a good idea.